# When is getApplicationContext() of Application class called?

Tags: android, android-context

I have an `Application` class in which i override `getApplicationContext()`.

I've looked in the Android Source code and I'm unable to find from where it's called?

The inheritance hierarchy is:

`Application -> ContextWrapper -> Context`

```
public abstract Context getApplicationContext();
```

`getApplicationContext()` is an abstract method in `Context` class which is overridden in `ContextWrapper` class.

```
@Override
public Context getApplicationContext() {
    return mBase.getApplicationContext();
}
```

`mBase` is reference to an object of type `Context` which is initialized in ContextWrapper's constructor but as per the code Application's class constructor passes null to the constructor of `super()` i.e. constructor of `ContextWrapper`.

```
public Application() {
    super(null);
}
```

Now the only possible way to pass context is via :

```
protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
    if (mBase != null) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Base context already set");
    }
    mBase = base;
}
```

but there is no call to this method either. Please help me in finding that from where is `getApplicationContext()` called then?

**NOTE :** Please don't post any links to such questions as I've gone through each one of them but still no concrete answer.

Comment: check `ContextImpl` on grepcode out

Comment: Yes I've seen it. Could you please elaborate how it works?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I guess the question is rather "where is `attachBaseContext()` called for the `Application` object?"

See [Application.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base.git/+/master/core/java/android/app/Application.java):

```
/**
 * @hide
 */
/* package */ final void attach(Context context) {
    attachBaseContext(context);
    mLoadedApk = ContextImpl.getImpl(context).mPackageInfo;
}
```

If you go a little further up the call chain, you will find `Instrumentation.newApplication()` ([Instrumentation.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base.git/+/master/core/java/android/app/Instrumentation.java)) and finally `LoadedApk.makeApplication()` ([LoadedApk.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/app/LoadedApk.java)), which are called as the application is being started:

```
    java.lang.ClassLoader cl = getClassLoader();
    ContextImpl appContext = new ContextImpl();
    appContext.init(this, null, mActivityThread);
    app = mActivityThread.mInstrumentation.newApplication(cl, appClass, appContext);
    ...
    mApplication = app;
```

In short, the base Context supplied to the `Application` class is a [`ContextImpl`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/app/ContextImpl.java) instance, created right in this method.

And, if you check `ContextImpl.getApplicationContext()`:

```
@Override
public Context getApplicationContext() {
    return (mPackageInfo != null) ? mPackageInfo.getApplication() : mMainThread.getApplication();
}
```

you'll see that it actually ends up calling `LoadedApk.getApplication()` (since `mPackageInfo` is the `LoadedApk` instance), which is the `mApplication` field set by the `makeApplication()` method mentioned before.

In short, after all this is set up, `Application.getApplicationContext()` ends up returning... the very same `Application` instance. :)

Comment: Is Android's source code incomplete in grepcode because as per grepcode `attach()` has no mention of `mLoadedApk = ContextImpl.getImpl(context).mPackageInfo;`. Source : http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.2_r1.1/android/app/Application.java#70

Comment: @AndroidWarrior You are looking into Android source code version `Version 2.2 r1.1` which was released on `30 June 2010`. Take a look at latest code which is shared in my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24933443/2083078).

Comment: @AndroidWarrior When in doubt, always check https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base.git/+/master (or more generically, https://android.googlesource.com/) which is the official AOSP repository. Both github and grepcode are mirrors, and not always fully in sync.

Answer (score 6):

`Context` is set through `setBaseContext` method, when an Activity / Service / Receiver instance is created for the first time. Here is the call stack:

[ContextWrapper::attachBaseContext](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4.2_r1/android/content/ContextWrapper.java?av=f#67) <-- [Application::attach](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4.2_r1/android/app/Application.java#180) <-- [Instrumentation::newApplication](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4.2_r1/android/app/Instrumentation.java#991) <-- [LoadedApk::makeApplication](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4.2_r1/android/app/LoadedApk.java?av=f#511) <--  [ActivityThread::performLaunchActivity](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4.2_r1/android/app/ActivityThread.java#2128) || [ActivityThread::handleReceiver](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4.2_r1/android/app/ActivityThread.java#2406) || [ActivityThread::handleCreateService](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4.2_r1/android/app/ActivityThread.java#2568) || [ActivityThread::handleBindApplication](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4.2_r1/android/app/ActivityThread.java#4317)

Answer (score 0):

```
 public class ContactManagerApplication extends Application {
public static Context context = null;

 @Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Log.d("@gaurav", getApplicationContext()+"");
    context = getApplicationContext();

}
```

Comment: Please elaborate your answer. Explain what the solution is and not merely paste code.